# unable to run repair using -dc like -local parameter

Tags: cassandra

I am running C* 3.11.
What is difference between below two commands ?
Here -dc parameter is not working fine while -local works .
Any reason?

$nodetool repair -local -pr demo msisdn

**output :** Repair completed successfully

$nodetool repair -dc datacenter1 -pr demo msisdn

**output :**  error: Primary range repair should be performed on all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Can you provide the details of the keyspaces, potentially one is a simpleStrategy is my guess

Comment: CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '2', 'datacenter2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

Comment: $nodetool repair -local -pr demo msisdn      

I am running the above command from datacenter1 

Isn't both commands are same !!

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on https://community.datastax.com/questions/11796/ and I'm re-posting my answer here.

The `-local` and `-dc` flags limit the replicas which are repaired to a specific data centre.

Unlike localised repairs, primary range repairs (with the `-pr` flag) are designed to repair all replicas in all data centres. You can not use the `-dc` flag with `-pr` since they are mutually exclusive.

For more information, see [Manual repairs in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html). Cheers!